# Highlighting duplicate values in a single column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check the duplicates in G column and highlight in red if there is any duplicate. I wrote the below query but it is not working and throwing the error message as

> Unable to get the CountIf property of the WorksheetFunction class

```
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim g As Range

Set Rng1 = Range(Range("G11"), Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each g In Rng1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng1, g.Value) > 1 Then
         g.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next g
```

Comment: I assume you name a function/sub/variable like `WorksheetFunction`? Don't do that! • And replace `WorksheetFunction` with `Application.WorksheetFunction` • But actually I recommend to use Conditional Formatting for this task (you don't need to use VBA to highlight the duplicates).

Comment: still I am getting the below error Unable to get the CountIf property of the WorksheetFunction class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rng = .Range("G11:G" & .cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)

        For Each cell In rng
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cell) > 1 Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: GLad to hear that is working. dont forget to vote for the answer.